# Android 4.0 emulator default widget height

Tags: android, widget, emulation

I'm testing out my application in the Android 4.0 emulator and I'm having an issue with widget size. My widget (taken from the AOSP music app) is defined as:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="294dip"
    android:minHeight="72dip"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/appwidget_one"
    >
</appwidget-provider>
```

and the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/appwidget_bg">

   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/appwidget_one"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/appwidget_button_left"
        android:paddingLeft="18dip"
        android:paddingRight="8dip"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/appwidgetone_text"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="10dip"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/artist"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/appwidgetone_text"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="10dip"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/appwidget_divider"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/control_play"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_appwidget_music_play"
        android:background="@drawable/appwidget_button_center"
        android:scaleType="center"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/appwidget_divider"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/control_next"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_appwidget_music_next"
        android:background="@drawable/appwidget_button_right"
        android:scaleType="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

In the 2.3 emulator (and all versions below) the widget only takes up 1 cell in height and 4 in width (1 x 4) However, it takes up 2 cells for the height in the Android 4.0 emulator, making it 2 x 4 by default. Can someone tell me why this is happening and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Widget sizes are changed a bit
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html#anatomy_determining_size

To make your widget at one line try to change 294 to 250 (four columns) and 72 to 40 (one row):

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="250dip"
    android:minHeight="40dip"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/appwidget_one"
    >
</appwidget-provider>
```